# Circular view path error when adding swagger-springmvc dependency in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, swagger

I have a web service application that I am building using spring (ver 4.0.1) REST. I have created different projects for different resources say A & B and a common dynamic web project C. I am using gradle as build tool. Projects A & B are defined as dependency in project C. I have integrated swagger-springmvc:0.8.5 for REST API documentation. I am using Java based spring configuration and my spring & swagger configuration files are part of project C.

When I add swagger-springmvc dependency only in project C, it builds and works fine through eclipse (I run tomcat through eclipse). I can see my REST APIs doc for all the resources in project A & B.

But, if I add swagger-springmvc dependency in any of the project A or B (to add documentation on my resource or model classes), it builds fine but gives circular path error when tomcat is running through eclipse.

Following is the error if I want to access my resource '/authenticate' ('/authenticate' returns json type object):

```
avax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [authenticate]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL** [/cloudservice/authenticate] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:292)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:214)
...
```

But a call to resource '/api-docs' works fine and I can see the resource listing.

One thing to note, everything works fine if I build my application using gradle build from command line and copies the war file in the tomcat directory.

I am using JDK 1.7. Setting is also done is eclipse to use JDK 1.7.

I have added the required annotations in my webapp config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger
@ComponentScan("package")
@Profile
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigureAdapter {
    public void addInterceptors... {
    }
}
```

Following is the swagger config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger
@ComponentScan("package")
@Profile
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation() {
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(springSwaggerConfig);
    }
}
```

Swagger dependency is added in the gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.mangofactory:swagger-springmvc:0.8.5"
}
```

Following is the controller class code for resource '/authenticate':

```
@RestController
@Api(value = "authenticate", description = "authenticate")
public class AuthenticationResource {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public MyObj authenticateUser(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String authString {
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

The issue comes even if I remove @Api annotation from the resource class but swagger-springmvc dependency is added in the gradle build file.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from other forum. Sharing here in case someone gets the same issue.

In my eclipse projects A & B (resource & model classes), I am just using swagger annotations. So, I just required to add dependency on swagger-annotations not other swagger jars. I removed the dependency on swagger-springmvc (that in turns has dependency on other jars) and added swagger-annotations.

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.wordnik:swagger-annotations:1.3.5"
}
```

This fixes the problem.